# Can't access variable in data class kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, variables, scope, data-class

why can't I access a variable from another class? (the variable is in the data class, and when I want to access it, it throws "unresolved reference")

Here's what It looks like:

The code that tries to access the variable:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class questionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question)
        var nameDisplay: TextView = findViewById(R.id.nameDisplay)
        var name2 = usernameStore.username //here's the error, the "username" thing is red
        nameDisplay.setText(name2)

    }
}
```

The data Class:

```
package com.ketchup.myquizzies

public data class usernameStore (
   var username: String
)
```

Any help appreciated guys, I literally searched all things that came to my mind to solve this, but I couldn't help myself :(

Android Studio, Kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usernameStore` is a *`class`*, not an *`object`*. You need to create an instance of `usernameStore` to be able to use it.

```kotlin
class questionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val store = usernameStore()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question)
        var nameDisplay: TextView = findViewById(R.id.nameDisplay)
        var name2 = store.username
        nameDisplay.setText(name2)

    }
}
```

FWIW, creating instances of classes is covered by [this section](https://commonsware.com/Kotlin/pages/chap-classes-002.html) of [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Kotlin/pages/chap-classes-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Kotlin).

Comment: Also: remember: Class names must be mixed case, with the first letter of each inner word capitalized (CamelCase). In that case: 'QuestionActivity', 'UsernameStore'.

Comment: @Arnaldo: That is a popular *convention*. However, AFAIK, there are no capitalization rules for Kotlin classes.

Answer (score 1):

***You have not created instance of class***

usernameStore

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class questionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question)
    var nameDisplay: TextView = findViewById(R.id.nameDisplay)
   // replace with below code
    var name2 = usernameStore().username
    nameDisplay.setText(name2)

 }
}
```